# Adding and deleting clones?

Tags: jquery, clone

Can anyone tell me why these two adding and deleting clone btton wont work together?
http://jsfiddle.net/NXcxg/4

```
$("#addArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    $(".question21:last").after($(".question21:first").clone(true));
});

$("#deleteArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    if ($(".question21").length != 1) $(".question21:last").remove();
});

$("#addChild").click(function(){
        $(".question20:last").after($(".question20:first").clone(true));
    });

    $("#deleteChild").click(function() {
        if($(".question20").length!=1)
        $(".question20:last").remove();
     });
});
```

Comment: I edited your question, I hope you didn't forget to close the statements.. I assumed it was on accident.

Comment: yeah it was a paste error but working in fiddle just not my actual code

Comment: did you add the script under dom ready handler

Comment: also make sure that there are no errors in your browser console

Comment: just put your whole code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#deleteChild` click handler is not properly closed

```
$("#addArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    $(".question21:last").after($(".question21:first").clone(true));
});

$("#deleteArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    if ($(".question21").length != 1) $(".question21:last").remove();
});

$("#addChild").click(function(){
    $(".question20:last").after($(".question20:first").clone(true));
});

$("#deleteChild").click(function() {
    if($(".question20").length!=1)
        $(".question20:last").remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3u5cs/)

Comment: the awkward thing is i have it right in my code i didnt paste it right into fiddle any reason why it works in fillde and not in my code

Comment: @user2430661 also make sure that there are no errors in your browser console